# Appended a node group, but can't find it

Tags: materials, node-editor

I found a custom node of youtuber Blender_Guru's tutorial and appended it into "Node Tree"file ,but couldn't find it in "add node-group".(I have tried to restarted my computer but still couldn't find it in group or searching...)

[Nodegroup on Poliigon's Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b8p5nmg7evqbsd6/PoliigonUberMapping_v1.0.blend?dl=0)

tutorial:
[image]

my blender:
[image]

hope anyone can helping me with this problem..
(it seems very dumb but it really confused me)

Comment: Hello :). Works just fine in my 2.81, maybe just try to append it again.

Comment: Hello(^ ^;;) tried append it again and it works now....,thank you very much..(I'm so dumb)

Comment: Happy to help :). And don't feel dumb, it happens to everyone.

Comment: I ran into this in Blender 3.2.2 and I solved it by switching from the Compositor node graph to the Shader node graph before shift-a